# How does the geometric Frobenius act on stalk?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

[image]

[image]

How does the geometric Frobenius act on stalk? The first image is from [http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/Weil2seminar/Notes/L19.pdf](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/Weil2seminar/Notes/L19.pdf) page 9. The second image is from Kiehl-Weissauer page 7.

Comment: What is a "Weil sheaf"? Include a definition.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03QW .

Take special care for as the embedding to closure changes, the gluing in the colimit reflects it.